# Is there any way to remove an emblem?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-emblems

Since an emblem is neither a card nor a permanent, and doesn't have a card type (as per rule 113.5, shown below), "has no name, no types, no mana cost, and no color" (rule 113.3, also below), and (as pointed out by murgatroid99) *isn't even on the battlefield in the first place* (rule 113.1, ... also below), is there any way to either nullify or destroy/exile it?

> 113.5. An emblem is neither a card nor a permanent. Emblem isn’t a card type.
>
> 113.3. An emblem has no characteristics other than the abilities defined by the effect that created it. In
>   particular, an emblem has no name, no types, no mana cost, and no color.
>
> 113.1. Some effects put emblems into the command zone. An emblem is a marker used to represent an
>   object that has one or more abilities, but no other characteristics.

Comment: I would like to mention that since Emblems are not permanents, they are also not on the battlefield. They exist in a separate zone called the command zone [CR 113.1].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are currently no cards that explicitly remove emblems. The only way to get rid of an emblem is by activating the last loyalty ability on [Karn Liberated](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKarn%20Liberated%5d). This restarts the game, and resets everything in the game except a specific set of cards that he keeps track of.

Mechanically, an emblem is intended to be a reward, in some sense, for completing a somewhat complicated process: casting a Planeswalker, adding to its loyalty for multiple turns, and then activating its expensive ability, all while keeping your opponent from messing up the plan. Because they are so hard to obtain, they are correspondingly difficult to remove. Some are easier to obtain, like the one from [Gideon, Ally of Zendikar](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGideon%2c%20Ally%20of%20Zendikar%5d), but they are also weaker.

Comment: "so hard to obtain" / "correspondingly difficult to remove." You might be understating how difficult they are to remove, considering they're impossible to remove except from a restart-the-game effect. :P

Answer (score -3):

there is away to get rid of them restart the game there is a few cards that restart the game so in all restarting the game is the only way to counter emblems  Karn Liberated

Comment: This is simply a far worse restatement of the already existing answer.